# Hello world in clean pig workspace

Tags: apache-pig

I wonder wheter it is possible to do the classic 'Hello world!' in Apache Pig.

Pig is somewhat related to SQL and hive where one could simply do:

```
SELECT 'Hello Wold';
```

However, I have been unable to find a way to 'create something from nothing' in Pig.

---

Note that if you are able to load in 1 line of data or more, you could of course do the following:

1. Load
2. limit 1
3. Generate Hello World

However, this is not what I am looking for. I hope to find a way to create a hello world example without having any kind of data available.

In case you wonder: I am mostly asking this out of curiosity, but it could also be convenient to speed up the testing of code by just doing something in code (without having to touch the file system).

Comment: not sure that I understand what you are asking .... do you want a way to run ping in unit test (localy)?

Comment: @Mzf Not sure where ping and unit test come in. I just want to generate Hello World and be able to dump it or write it to a simple file using pigstorage.

Comment: but where are you going to run this pig ? from the pig shell ?

Comment: i think it is a good question! i was wondering whether it is possible or not. well technically How would pig understand what to print (or DUMP) untill and unless you feed him with some data (load small text file containing Hello world as text string) ??

Comment: @Mzf I could run it from the pig shell or just by executing a pig file. I have not experienced any differences between those cases yet that appear to be relevant in this case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After all these years, I am now fairly confident that it is NOT possible to create something from nothing with Apache Pig.